# Swing PixelGrabber - Sorting Data

Tags: java, image, swing, image-processing

I am working on sorting an images colors into a 2d array (rows/columns) of colors. I've implemented a `PixelGrabber`, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly whats happening, and what I can do with `data` to sort into a 2d array. Thanks!

```
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
    PixelGrabber grabber = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
    if (grabber.grabPixels()) {
        int width = grabber.getWidth();
        int height = grabber.getHeight();
        int[][] imageColors = new int[width][height]; //I want to store colors in here
        int[] data = (int[]) grabber.getPixels();
     }
 } catch (Exception f) {
 }
```

Comment: There's an [example in the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html) that demonstrates how to extract the color components from the pixel data. You could also mix it with [this example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt.image/how-to-use-pixelgrabber-class-to-acquire-pixel-data-from-an-image-o.html)

Comment: What does the >> operator do in `int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;`?

Comment: It extracts the color components from the packed int, in this, it's extract the alpha component of the color

Comment: I would really advise against using `PixelGrabber` with a `BufferedImage`. It really is just a very slow way of doing the same thing as `img.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w)`. The `PixelGrabber` class is intended for use with the old `ImageProducer/Consumer` API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the pixel array returned from `PixelGrabber` is a one dimensional array of the pixel data, which is basically a "flat" representation of the image data

To get a particular pixel at a given x/y position, you need to offset the position in the array by `(y * width) + x`. So to copy the pixel data from the one dimensional array to your two dimensional array, you would need a compound for loop. For example...

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        imageColors[x][y] = data[(y * width) + x];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works really well! Just one quick question, what type of format is the color stored in before we do the `int alpha = (pixel>>24)...` stuff? If theres a certain name for it, it'll make it easier to research and use in a raw format.

Comment: It's comply know as a packed int or packed byte depending on the type of image. You can also use Color(int, boolean), passing the packed int to the Color class and the boolean is used to determine if the alpha but should be extracted as well, personally, I find it simpler as I don't need to remember the bit wise calculations